# What is the recommended size of indentation in Python?

Tags: python, indentation

Is there any **official** rule/proposal on how should the Python code be indented?

Comment: The search engine of your choice should yield what you are looking for by searching for "PEP 8"

Comment: I'm new to Python, didn't know until the answer to this question.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) (Python's official style guide):

> Use 4 spaces per indentation level.

Answer (score 1):

4 spaces, or hitting the tab button once. However, try to avoid the tab button. Sometimes it will give you indentation errors even when you indent correctly.

Comment: :set expandtab :D